# HTTP request duration with HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

Is it possible to monitor the **duration of HTTP requests**? (from the moment that the request is received by the load balancer, to the time when the response is returned to the client by the load balancer)

I would like to monitor this metric in the frontend, because I want to include the queue time. If I measure the duration of the backend I may get good stats but the real performance can be bad (for example if the request gets queued in the load balancer itself).

For example I would like to monitor a web application during traffic spikes to make sure that the responses are still fast, from the point of view of the user (e.g. < 3 seconds).

Answer (score 9):

HAproxy offers all those informations in the logs .

see [Haproxy HTTP Log Format](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#8.2.3)

In particular you are looking for the section number 6 ,

> 6   TR '/' Tw '/' Tc '/' Tr '/' Ta*                       10/0/30/69/109

where

> - "TR" is the total time in milliseconds spent waiting for a full HTTP
>     request from the client (not counting body) after the first byte was
>     received. It can be "-1" if the connection was aborted before a complete
>     request could be received or the a bad request was received. It should
>     always be very small because a request generally fits in one single packet.
>     Large times here generally indicate network issues between the client and
>     haproxy or requests being typed by hand. See "Timers" below for more details.
> - "Tw" is the total time in milliseconds spent waiting in the various queues.
>     It can be "-1" if the connection was aborted before reaching the queue.
>     See "Timers" below for more details.
> - "Tc" is the total time in milliseconds spent waiting for the connection to
>     establish to the final server, including retries. It can be "-1" if the
>     request was aborted before a connection could be established. See "Timers"
>     below for more details.
> - "Tr" is the total time in milliseconds spent waiting for the server to send
>     a full HTTP response, not counting data. It can be "-1" if the request was
>     aborted before a complete response could be received. It generally matches
>     the server's processing time for the request, though it may be altered by
>     the amount of data sent by the client to the server. Large times here on
>     "GET" requests generally indicate an overloaded server. See "Timers" below
>     for more details.
> - "Ta" is the time the request remained active in haproxy, which is the total
>     time in milliseconds elapsed between the first byte of the request was
>     received and the last byte of response was sent. It covers all possible
>     processing except the handshake (see Th) and idle time (see Ti). There is
>     one exception, if "option logasap" was specified, then the time counting
>     stops at the moment the log is emitted. In this case, a '+' sign is
>     prepended before the value, indicating that the final one will be larger.
>     See "Timers" below for more details.

Exporting those metrics from the logs to a more useful format / backend can be done in many ways, Logstash comes to mind since it can parse those logs and send them to many different backends